# New blog engine broke list numbering in Gorilla vs Shark

Tags: bug, blog

Rereading the [Gorilla vs Shark post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) on the new blog engine this morning to point a user asking such a question to it, I noticed that the numbering is broken.

Specifically, instead of

1. Some Stuff

   some paragraph stuff here
2. Some more stuff

   some paragraph stuff here
3. Yet more stuff

It now looks like:

`1`.  Some stuff

some paragraph stuff here

`1`.  Some more stuff

some paragraph stuff here

`1`.  Yet more stuff

(I use `1` here, as Meta would correctly render this as 1/2/3.  The shading is not in the blog post.)

Either the post needs to be revisited to fix the numbers - or the blog engine perhaps needs some tweaking to not break list numbering?

This is on Chrome 48.0.2564.116 and Windows 7.  I can also reproduce it on IE 11.